# What effect does weak wifi/4g have on network calls

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I am frontend dev, developing in react-native, so i am not strictly a mobile developer. I was wondering what effect weak wifi/4g has on the payload that is being delivered/received from the server? Would it take longer to send a payload to the server if the signal is weak? If there is any other considerations for weak signal on mobile it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: One question for you how will you know that mobile is getting low speed in weak signals?

Comment: It will works the same way that a computer with a weak network connection. This question is not related to development please refer to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to know how and where to ask your question.